# IOS Universal link association between my app and website not working

Tags: ios, qt, cmake, ios-universal-links

I'm using Qt creator to build an iOS, iPadOS Qt app. I'm following [this Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/supporting-associated-domains#Add-the-associated-domains-entitlement-to-your-app) to associate Universal links to my app.

I placed the apple-app-site-association file in the .well-known directory as documented.

```
// Note: The Team ID and the app bundle identifier are correct. I printed the bundle ID programatically and pasted here.
{
    "applinks": {
        "details": [
           {
               "appIDs": [ "<Team ID>.<bundle identifier>" ],
               "components": [
                 {
                     "comment": "Match any url (testing)"
                 }
               ]
           }
        ]
    }
}
```

This is in the website side.

In the app side, I have set the associated-domains key as follows

```
// file name - IOSQtLaunchUsingLinks.entitlements

// Note: If my website's URL is https://sample.github.io, I pasted 'sample.github.io' in place of '<website>' below.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>com.apple.developer.associated-domains</key>
        <array>
                <string>applinks:<website></string>
        </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

This entitlement file is set using CMake as follows:

```
set_target_properties (appIOSQtLaunchUsingLinks PROPERTIES
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_INFO_PLIST "info.plist.in"
    XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS "IOSQtLaunchUsingLinks.entitlements"
)
```

The above steps worked in a native iOS project - If I click my website link, the app launches. But in a Qt iOS project created using CMake, clicking the website link always launches the website and not the app.

Not sure what have I missed. Please help.